# How to convert composite AV signal or RGB to luma (grayscale)?

Tags: video, rgb, tv

As the title says- how can you convert composite signal into luma?? As we all know, composite is just what it says, composite video with grayscale and color signal combined and luma is just grayscale. I have an idea how to approach this but I have no idea how to finish it. LM1881 chip seems to be a good candidate to start as it can separate sync signal and, most importantly, it can output 'color burst and back porch' signal active.

Datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1881.pdf

My idea is to use composite signal as is and remove color burst signal from it using LM1881. To my knowledge, this should work in theory. This sounds simple on paper but I'm not sure how to approach this. Those 2 signals should probably be gated somehow. Should I use some sort of multiplexer, resistors or transistors?? If that approach doesn't work then maybe it's possible to combine all RGB + sync signals and make luma output that way?? Thanks for your suggestions in advance

EDIT: oh goodness, I forgot composite signal contains color subcarrier throughout the whole signal so this would probably mean filtering out everything and taking PAL/NTSC into consideration...
https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/374500C-01/oscopefunds/composite_component_video_signals/

So maybe combining R+G+B signals and mixing them with composite sync sounds like a better idea. In this scenario PAL and NTSC differences will not matter. According to formula, RGB should be mixed like this: Y = 0.2126 R + 0.7152 G + 0.0722 B. So once again, what is the best way to approach this?? I suppose resistors + op-amp are required at least and most importantly, sync also needs to be combined somehow.

Comment: Bandstop filter out the colour subcarrier and its sidebands. More economically, lowpass filter somewhere below the CSC (there isn't much luma information above the upper colour sideband anyway) Details depend which composite signal you have (but PAL G, Pal I and SECAM can share the same filter)

Comment: Re: your edit: actually if you suppress the colorburst, most receivers will ignore the color subcarrier (they have a "color killer circuit" for B&W compatibility). That's why weak signals sometimes have no/intermittent color, and static shows up as black and white snow.

Comment: @hobbs that is true, but the chroma information still appears as speckle on a monochrome monitor (unless it has the bandstop/lowpass filter built in). This has even been used to recover colour pictures from monochrome film recordings! https://colour-recovery.fandom.com/wiki/The_Unofficial_Colour_Recovery_Wiki (Richard Russell was my supervisor in 1981)

Comment: @user_1818839 sure. That might or might not be okay. We don't really have any info on the use-case in the question, unfortunately :)